# Select ranked records whose sum adds up to a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
+----+--------+----------+-----------+
| ID | Number | Reason   | Timestamp |
+----+--------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 2      | Business | date      |
|  2 | 3      | Pleasure | date      |
+----+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I've got a table that looks like above. I'm trying to figure out how I can get the latest records (table ranked by timestamp) whose Number columns add up to a certain value.

So in the above example, if I had a value of 5, I would want these 2 records (assuming they were the most recent). I would like to get an output string like the following:

```
2 (Business), 3 (Pleasure)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `value` a parameter? Is `Number` unique? Do you want all combinations or only from two previous records?

Comment: Do they have to add up exactly?  Or are you looking for the first group that add up to at least that amount?

Comment: @TimSchmelter value would actually be from another table. number is not unique. I want the the previous records that add up to value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no they don't have to add up exactly. greater than or equal is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the most recent records that add up to no more than X, then you need a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2008, this is handled using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(number) from t t2 where t2.id <= t.id) as CumeSumValue
      from t
     ) t
where CumeSumValue <= X
```

I think `>=` requires a bit more logic.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(number)
              from t t2
              where t2.id <= t.id
             ) as CumeSumValue
      from t
     ) t
where CumeSumValue <= X or   -- less than or equal
      ((CumeSumValue - Number < X) and (CumeSumValue > X))  -- first that is greater than
      CumeSumValue >= X
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a **cursor**?

This looks like the prime example for using a cursor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms180169.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At first you should get latest records

```
Select Max(ID) MAXID Into #t From t Group By Timestamp
```

Now in #t all latest records available . You can join in with table to access all fields :

```
Select t.* from t Join #t on t.ID = #t.MAXID
```

If you want to filter something it could be done with simple where clause of having .